# How to change triangle in ComboBox qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

How do I change the size and color of the triangle in a ComboBox? And also flip the triangle?

Now it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the Material style.

Without declaring your own [indicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#indicator-prop):

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        model: 10

        Binding {
            target: comboBox.indicator
            property: "rotation"
            value: 180
        }
        Binding {
            target: comboBox.indicator
            property: "color"
            value: "tomato"
        }
    }
}
```

Declaring your own `indicator`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ComboBox {
        id: comboBox
        model: 10
        indicator: ColorImage {
            x: comboBox.mirrored ? comboBox.padding : comboBox.width - width - comboBox.padding
            y: comboBox.topPadding + (comboBox.availableHeight - height) / 2
            color: "tomato"
            rotation: 180
            source: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls/Material/images/drop-indicator.png"
        }
    }
}
```

Both approaches assume something about the QML implementation of the style in use:

- The first approach assumes that the indicator has a `color` property. This could change in a future version (although it's very unlikely).
- The second approach uses an internal resource URL (for convenience, since it's an image that everyone testing this code should have available on their machines), but I wouldn't generally encourage doing so yourself. If you're sure that your application will use the Material style, then it should be fine, but again, this path could change in a future version. If you want a more future-proof option, use your own image for the `indicator`.

If you want a completely future-proof option, implement your own style:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#definition-of-a-style

Qt 6 version of that page:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#definition-of-a-style